# Please Correct my SQL Syntax

Tags: vb6

I know that there's something wrong with my syntax... `"select * from tblpayroll where empid = userid"`

UserID is a variable...

Comment: you need to provide more detail. Is this a stored procedure you're writing? = @userid Is this in your vb code? and userID is a vb variable? `"select * from tblpayroll where empid = " & userId`

Comment: I have provided more details of my question... but I made it more simple... Hope you could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not edit your questions in such a way that the nature totally changes. It makes all answers to date useless. If you have a fundamentally different question (and it was fundamentally different despite being about the same program), please ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice... please post back my question and let me do this.

Comment: if you click on the "yesterday" above where it says "edited yesterday paxdiablo" then click on "view source" for revision 3 (the one before I changed it back to the original), you can copy and paste that text into a brand new question. That's the easiest way to achieve what you want. If it's not, leave another message with the text '@pax' somewhere in it so I'll be notified by SO automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text `"select * from tblpayroll where empid = userid"` will be sent through *exactly as is* to the SQL back end, the `userid` part will not be substituted. So, unless you have a `userid` column, you'll probably get an error. Even if you *do* have a `userid` column, the results won't be what you expect.

What you need to do depends on whether `userid` is a numeric or string value. For numerics, you can use:

```
"select * from tblpayroll where empid = " & CStr(userid)
```

This will first turn the numeric value into a string and check it as-is.

For string values, use:

```
"select * from tblpayroll where empid = '" & userid & "'"
```

This will simply surround the string with quotes to ensure a string comparison works. You need to be aware that this is a bad idea if `userid` has not been sanitised somehow - it may lead to SQL injection attacks. The art of fixing that is outside the scope of this particular question but it's worth keeping in mind.

What to do if your variable is numeric but the database field is a string is another matter. You can do it with `CStr` and zero-padding but, since it's an unlikely scenario, I haven't documented it here.

Comment: ...It was of help to me, but it only gets a single set of record. What I mean is, for instance, the value of UserID is A52, so, all the Records with the UserID of A52 must must appear in textboxes respectively.

Comment: @aerohn, that query will return all rows satisfying that condition. If you're only getting one then either (1) there is only one row, quite possible if the table is an employee-type table (one row per employee) rather than a payrun-type table (eg, one row per employee per month); or (2) you're not processing the returned row set correctly.

Comment: Your string values example suffers from a SQL injection bug.

Comment: @rpetrich, it _may_ suffer from such, yes. It all depends on where `userid` is coming from and whether it's already been sanitised. But that has absolutely nothing to do with the question at hand. You could equally well complain that the column might not be indexed or that it doesn't follow some coding standard or that it should be a stored procedure. If I delivered perfect, full-blown solutions rather than answering the question in a targeted manner, my answers would become even _more_ tedious, boring and hard to read. Surely none of us here want that? :-)

Comment: A variable named `userid` implies unsanitized input. Knowingly posting something that suffers from such a security hole is irresponsible.

Comment: A variable named `userid` implies _nothing_ more than the fact that it probably contains a user ID. It may well have come from a drop-down list which was set up with a query from the database hence it would be impossible for it to be injectable. It may have come from the user as dangerous free-form text but have already been through a sanitisation process. Without knowing its source, the assumption that it's dangerous is exactly that - just an assumption. But I'll modify the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

apparently, it's your vb variable.

```sql
select * from tblpayroll where empid = '" & userid & "' "
```

use it this way, and it'll work

Comment: ...It was of help to me, but it only gets a single set of record. What I mean is, for instance, the value of UserID is *A52*, so, all the Records with the UserID of *A52* must must appear in textboxes respectively.

Comment: @aerohn that is a much different question. If you want the answer to that, mark one of the answers here as correct and open a new question with details regarding how you get the data from the database and what textboxes you have - you will likely want to provide code so that people can understand what you're asking